# How to fill in the blanks for one (or more) columns by calculating based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I collect and process hundreds of jumbled tables every day, and some of the data requires attention.

[image: sample data]

(Sorry for my English and typography skills)

The item with **[LEVEL]"S"** rarely appears, and when it happens(row 3,6), if the **["Check"]** column is **"Go"**(row 6), the **blank** of the target column needs to be filled in.  (If not empty, the original value is retained)

1. The blank in the **["FillNA"]** column needs to be filled with **"DANGER"**.

(2. If possible, the blank in the **["Detail"]** column needs to be filled with the **row number** of the dataframe && the action indicated in the **["Check"]** column.)

```
N = pd.NA  
df= pd.DataFrame({  "LEVEL":["E","D","C","S","A","B","S","A","B","C"],
                    "CHECK":["HELLO",N ,N,"Keep",N,N,"Go",N,N,N],
                    "FillNA":["WORLD",N ,N,"Data",N,N,N,N,N,N],
                    "Detail":[N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N] })
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output from this data?

Comment: sorry...  `6  ,   S   ,  Go ,  DANGER  , 6 Go`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC,

```py
m = df['LEVEL'].eq('S') & df['CHECK'].eq('Go')
df['FillNA'] = df['FillNA'].mask(m & df['FillNA'].isna(), 'DANGER')
df['Detail'] = df['Detail'].mask(m & df['Detail'].isna(), df.index.astype(str) + ' ' + df['CHECK'])

# or

cols = ['FillNA', 'Detail']
df.loc[m, cols] = df.loc[m, cols].fillna({'FillNA': 'DANGER', 'Detail': df.index.astype(str) + ' ' + df['CHECK']})
```

```
print(df)

  LEVEL  CHECK  FillNA Detail
0     E  HELLO   WORLD   <NA>
1     D   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
2     C   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
3     S   Keep    Data   <NA>
4     A   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
5     B   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
6     S     Go  DANGER   6 Go
7     A   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
8     B   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
9     C   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you, I beleive this works, I'll try this tonight ♡

Comment: The first method works, thank you! The second method looks more nifty, can you tell me how the **cols** in df.loc[m, **cols**] should be written, I wasn't able to try it, thanks again!

Comment: I am very strange here, even copy and paste the code of method 2, row6 can't get any modification. `m=... ; cols=... ; df.loc... ; print... `.  What is the problem? Thank you for the update!

Comment: @KongNan Sorry, forget to uncomment the previous `mask` when testing `loc`. I shouldn't use `inplace` with `loc`, updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this works, I'll test that as soon as possible ♡

Comment: Yes it works fine! Thank you ynjxsjmh!